# Access 2007: Append data to memo field using a command button

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a database based on the 'Issues.accdb' template, and I want to modify one of the forms.

In the 'Issue Details' form there is an open text box which appends data to a memo 'Comments' field when the  record is saved. The history of this comments field is shown in a locked text box below.

I want to change the behaviour of the form so that instead of the user entering a new comment into an open text field on the form, a command button is clicked and it opens an input box; the comment is then input into this.

I also want to enter validation so that no one can enter a blank comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way I could see to rigging what you already have to what you requested would be to do this:

Since you already have a bound memo field for the insertion, just make it invisible. In the onClick event for your command button, you'll just populate that memo field with an InputBox with something like

```
 dim cmt as String
 cmt = InputBox("Please provide a comment.")
 if cmt = "" then 
 msgbox("Comments cannot be empty")
 else
 me.myBoundMemofield = cmt
 docmd.save
```